# JavaScript - should i write "else" after "if" that throws exception?

Tags: javascript

What construction is better to use? If i am always throwing exception in `if` statement, then actually the code after `if` block will never be executed, so `else` isn't needed. But on the other side, blocks shouldn't be executed both, so it is maybe good practice to use `else` right?

**Version 1**

```
if (!this.regions[region]) {
    throw 'Component ignored: region ' + region + 'does not exists';
}
else {
    ....            
}
```

**Version 2**

```
if (!this.regions[region]) {
        throw 'Component ignored: region ' + region + 'does not exists';
}
......
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for the `else` clause because it makes no difference whether it's there or not.  The code after the `if` block executes only if the `if` statement is falsey because if it's truthy, then it throws the exception and never gets past the `if`.

This is very similar to something like this which is used pretty commonly:

```
function doSomething(a, b) {
   if (!a || b < 2) {
       return false;
   }
   // more code here
   return true;
}
```

Again, no `else` statement is needed because the code only gets beyond the `if` statement if it was `falsey` so all remaining code is already `else`.

You can use the `else`, but it is not required and adds no functionality.  I prefer not to use the else in these cases because it just leads to more code indentation than needed.

Answer (score 2):

Version 2 is called "short-circuit logic". If something goes wrong, abort. It's perfectly valid.

The code below the `throw` won't execute if the `throw` statement is reached.

Answer (score -1):

If you use with else it will execute `else` inside only the expression not match.

But if you not use else, it will execute expression and after `if` code as well. 
Moreover even if the expression not match or match after `if` will execute.

Comment: In this particular example, they do the same thing semantically.

Comment: I tried to tell, second version will continue after the if condition, even it is not matched. But First version will only return the correct condition.

Comment: Do you know what `throw` does? It's similar to how `return` works.